# Waterproof shoes for men for +10°..+15°C and full-day use

Tags: shoes

I am looking for shoes that I can wear for all day long in moderate outdoor conditions, both in rainy and dry conditions, at +10°C..+15°C (50°F..60°F). My feet sweet quite a lot, so breathability sustaining for long hours would be a great advantage.

The target conditions are:

- rainy day in a rural conditions, both walking a lot and sitting on an open-air terrace for long hours
- rainy day in a small town full of puddles and with lots of unpaved pathdays
- a cool day with a "chance of rain" when rain doesn't actually happen

What brands and product lines to look first? Which characteristics/features to look for? What keywords to search for in customer reviews to make sure given model is what I need?

How can I best explain what I need in a advanced-outdoor gear shop?
Or what stores should I actually look at?

Answer (score 2):

> What brands and product lines to look first?

Try as many as you can! The fit (not the brand) is the most important. Try on lots and see which ones feel the best.

> Which characteristics/features to look for?

For that temperature range you want something pretty cooling. Lighter, thinner material boots are likely your best bet.

It doesn't sound like your going anywhere too technical so try not to get drawn into all the jargon, etc. Most of this is just marketing spin anyway. Remember the sales person (though I'm sure will be helpful) is trying to get you to buy the most expensive boot he/she can.

> What keywords to search for in customer reviews to make sure given
>   model is what I need?

You want waterproof, so that's your staring point. Then it comes down to price and fit, like I said try not to get drawn into all the nonsense, your not doing anything overly difficult.

> How can I best explain what I need in a advanced-outdoor gear shop?

Don't be intimidated, it's s shop like any other. Talk to the staff (I find gear shop staff are typically very helpful) and explain what you want. I'd say your not after anything fancy or expensive but you want it to be waterproof, light and good for reasonably warm temperatures

> Or what stores should I actually look at?

All brands have pro's an con's, like I said try several pairs on and decide which one's work best for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have leather hiking shoes. I went to outdoors gear store and those were the first pair I tried and I fell in love. The pair of shoes were perfect match with my feet. It felt good to walk around.

Keeping leather shoes in good condition is a bit of constant work. Washing the outside after hiking in dirt and mud and always before waxing and wet proofing. Waxing keeps the leather in good condition and leather doesn't dry and fracture. Wet proofing adds the water resistance.

I also like to add insoles which can be removed when drying the shoe and replaced when too smelly.

And don't forget to use good, clean and dry socks.

Comment: Would you hint which brand and model it is? And does leather actually breathe well?

Answer (score 1):

---

## HI-TEC

You may or may not have seen the viral video that circulated a few years ago about Hi-Tec's water repellent shoes. If not, then you *have* to watch it: [Liquid Mountaineering.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oe3St1GgoHQ)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oe3St1GgoHQ

---

Hi-Tec has a whole line of water repellent shoes, including walking shoes:

[ALTO WATERPROOF MEN'S WALKING](http://www.hi-tec.com/uk/alto-waterproof-mens-walking-shoe-charcoal-grey-beacon.html)

[image]

Comment: Spoiler alert! Watch the video in the answer first, then watch this one - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ThZ5NrZel28

Comment: How breathable they are?

Comment: @yurkennis About as breathable as waterproof can get.